# php pushing pattern from array1 to array2

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I have an array that looks something like this

```
array(7) {
  [0]=> "hello,pat1"
  [1]=> "hello,pat1"
  [2]=> "test,pat2"
  [3]=> "test,pat2"
  [4]=> "foo,pat3"
  [5]=> "foo,pat3"
  [6]=> "foo,pat3"
  ....
}
```

I would like to push it into another array so the output of the array2 is as follow:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=> "hello,pat1"
  [1]=> "test,pat2"
  [2]=> "foo,pat3"
  [3]=> "foo,pat3"
  [4]=> "foo,pat3"
  [5]=> "hello,pat1"
  [6]=> "test,pat2"
  .....
}
```

What I want is to push them in the following pattern: **1 "pat1" 1 "pat2" and 3 "pat3"**, and repeat this pattern every 5 elements.

```
while ( !empty( $array1 ) )
  $a = explode(",",$array1[$i]);
  if($a[1]=='pat1' &&)
     push && unset
  elseif($a[1]=='pat2' &&)
     push && unset
  elseif($a[1]=='pat3' and < 5)
     push && unset and reset pattern counter
}
```

What would be a good way of doing this?

Any idea will be appreciate it.

Comment: Can you clarify your question slightly?  I am not really sure what you are trying to do here.  thx.

Comment: What I want is to push them into the other array but not in the same order as array1, but instead, push the first element as pat1, second element as pat2, and 3 more elements as pat3. This means that the "pattern" of 1,1,3 will be repeated for every 5 elements until all elements on array1 are gone. hope this clears it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time for some fun with the iterators of the [Standard PHP Library](http://docs.php.net/spl) :-)

```
<?php
$array1 = array (
  "hello1,pat1", "hello2,pat1", "hello3,pat1",
  "test1,pat2", "test2,pat2",
  "foo1,pat3", "foo2,pat3", "foo3,pat3",
  "foo4,pat3", "foo5,pat3", "foo6,pat3"
);

// "group by" patN
$foo = array();
foreach($array1 as $a) {
  // feel free to complain about the @ here ...to somebody else
  @$foo[ strrchr($a, ',') ][] = $a;
}
// split pat3 into chunks of 3
$foo[',pat3'] = array_chunk($foo[',pat3'], 3);

// add all "groups" to a MultipleIterator
$mi = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY);
foreach($foo as $x) {
  $mi->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator($x) );
}

// each call to $mi->current() will return an array
// with the current items of all registered iterators
foreach ($mi as $x) {
  // "flatten" the nested arrays
  foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($x)) as $e) {  
    echo $e, "\n";
  }
  echo "----\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd set respective counters with respective incrementation.  Since php will cast float keys to integers, you can just increment the `,pat3` items with `.33` instead of `1`.  Then, to flatten the result, just use `array_merge()` with the splat operator.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/V8tWR))

```
$array = [
    "hello1,pat1",
    "hello2,pat1",
    "test3,pat2",
    "test4,pat2",
    "foo5,pat3",
    "foo6,pat3",
    "foo7,pat3",
];

$counters = [',pat1' => 0, ',pat2' => 0, ',pat3' => 0];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $end = strrchr($value, ',');
    $groups[$counters[$end]][] = $value;
    $counters[$end] += ($end === ',pat3' ? .33 : 1);
}

var_export(array_merge(...$groups));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'hello1,pat1',
  1 => 'test3,pat2',
  2 => 'foo5,pat3',
  3 => 'foo6,pat3',
  4 => 'foo7,pat3',
  5 => 'hello2,pat1',
  6 => 'test4,pat2',
)
```